# What is causing a Stack Overflow in my code?

Tags: java

I'm just starting with java, so I'm trying to do a simple program that adds the elements of an array.
It's as simple as that. However, I keep getting a Stack Overflow Exception. It's a short code, but I seriously have spent near 1 hour trying to figure it out.
This page has helped me so much for almost 1 year already, but this time I couldn't find a case similar to mine, so I'm asking directly. 
And sorry for my bad english, I'm still just learning.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] row = {6 , -2 , 1 ,2 ,-8, 1};
    int result = arraySum(0, row.length-1, row);
    System.out.println(result);

}
public static int arraySum(int start, int end, int[] row)
{
    int len = end-start+1;
    if (len == 1)
    {
        return row[start];
    }
    int aux1 = arraySum(start, (len/2)-1, row);
    int aux2 = arraySum(len/2, end, row);
    return aux1 + aux2;
}
```

Comment: Have you gone through the execution of your code with a debugger or even pen and paper? I'm guessing your recursion isn't reaching its base case and is recursing forever.

Comment: `System.out.println(IntStream.of(row).sum());`

Comment: Your recursive calls have the wrong arguments.  Think carefully about what the start and end indexes of each subarray might be.  In particular, consider what happens when `start = 2` and `end = 5`.  Your _second_ recursion would have exactly the same arguments.

Comment: An hour is not long enough to warrant giving up -- keep at it! :) As you learn more programming, you're going to have to debug tougher and tougher problems. Debugging is a skill, and like any other it requires practice. I echo @AndrewLi's advice. The debugging skills you learn on this exercise will serve you as you move on to more complicated problems.

Comment: Thank you for your words!. It may not seem like it but you helped a lot. I think I found what I was looking for. I'll try harder before bothering you guys again. So thanks again for the quick response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the solution, but a hint for how to find the problem yourself.

Insert a print statement in the beginning of the recursive method, printing the parameters (no need to print the array).

```
public static int arraySum(int start, int end, int[] row)
{
    System.out.println(start + " " + end);
    // rest of method
}
```

The output will show how it goes wrong:

```
0 5
0 2
0 0
1 2
1 0
1 -1
1 -1
... many lines suppressed ...
1 -1
1 -1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    ... stack trace suppressed ...
```

This is one way to **debug** your program, and you need to learn how to debug. It is an essential skill for a programmer.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I actually have used print statements before for things like these, but I thought the Exception would made the code stop running.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an offset for caculating the index of the  middle value, so it's calling infinitely until your memory runs out

```
  int aux1 = arraySum(start, start+(len/2)-1, row);
  int aux2 = arraySum(start+len/2, end, row);
```